# vim not accepting abbreviation insertion before text

Tags: vim

i have this problem: i have this in my _vimrc:

> iab dd \mathrm{d}

and it works fine, **except** when I am editing a line and there is text on the right of the cursor (space or no space in between). Is there anything I can do to fix this? I couldn't find anything in the help files (or here!)..

thanks!

s.franky

Comment: Works fine for me with Vim 7.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution works fine, except that I want this to work only after I press space (this *is* what is meant by non-word character, right? So, I *am* typing a non-word character, only it doesn't work in all cases)
I don't get it. Why does it matter that other text follows, if I still press space?
thanks though, this is much better than the previous one not working at all!

@chris morgan: oddly, it's working for me too, sometimes, in an empty document. If I load up a tex document (latex-suite package), it's impossible. But I m not sure it's latex-suite specific. Sometimes this happens for .txt documents, too..

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly related to your question but regarding easy text completion, if you don't know it already, you should have a look at the [SnipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) plugin.

It inserts snippets of code depending on the context by a simple press of `<Tab>` key.

There is already a Tex snippet file that you can easily expand with your own abbreviations.

Comment: I use snipmate for larger pieces of (latex) content, I never thought about using it for mere abbreviations, but given that iab doesn't seem to be working inbetween text, I ll give this a try! thanks

Answer (score 0):

abbreviations like this will trigger when you enter a non-word character. Maybe what you want is rather an `inoremap`?

From the documentation:

> An abbreviation is only recognized
>   when you type a non-keyword character.
>   This can also be the <Esc> that ends
>   insert mode or the <CR> that ends a
>   command.  The non-keyword character
>   which ends the abbreviation is
>   inserted after the expanded
>   abbreviation.  An exception to this is
>   the character <C-]>, which is used to
>   expand an abbreviation without
>   inserting any extra characters.